# Calling a method in the same JavaScript/ModeJs class gives error

Tags: javascript, class

I have seen other similar questions, but they most seem to to suggest adding `this`, but I get the error despite having `this`:

When I run the code below I get:

```
TestDB.listOrgTests: Error:  TypeError: Cannot read property 'listTests' of undefined
    at /node/classes/TestDB.class.js:201:29
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at TestDB.listOrgTests (/node/classes/TestDB.class.js:189:14)
    at /node/index.js:116:22
    at /node/index.js:118:6
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/node/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at next (node/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:144:13)
    at Route.dispatch (/node/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:114:3)
```

```js
class TestDB {

  dbc = null;
  constructor() {
    console.log('new USerDB');
    this.dbClass = require('./db.class');
    this.db = new this.dbClass.db();
    this.dbc = this.db.dbConn;
  }

  async listTests(sql, id) {
    console.log('/listTests: ', id);

    var dbc = this.dbc;
    const ts = this.TestClass;
    var ta = new Array();

    return new Promise(async function(resolve, reject) {

      try {

        var values = [id];
        dbc.query(sql,
          values,
          function(err, row) {
            if (err) {
              throw err;
            }
            console.log("TestDB.listTests: Queried ID: " + id + " " + row.length + " rows");
            ta = [];
            for (var i = 0; i < row.length; i++) {

              // do Stuff

            }
            console.log('returned test array: ', ta);
            return resolve(ta);
          });
      } catch (err) {
        console.error("TestDB.listTests: Error: ", err);
        return (reject);
      }
    })
  }

  async listOrgTests(orgID) {
    console.log('/listOrgTests: ', orgID);

    const ts = this.TestClass;
    var ta = new Array();

    return new Promise(async function(resolve, reject) {
      const sql = `
             SELECT *
             FROM tests
             WHERE org_id = ?         
             ORDER BY test_cdate DESC
             `;
      try {
        ta = await this.listTests(sql, orgID);//<< ERROR HERE EVEN WITH this.
        return resolve(ta);
      } catch (err) {
        console.error("TestDB.listOrgTests: Error: ", err);
        return (reject);
      }
    })
  }
```

Comment: The `this` is incorrect since this doesn't point to the TestDB instance, because the Promise's function is not a method of the TestDB class. Use an arrow function `return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {` instead to retain `this` from the TestDB

Comment: [Never pass an `async function` as the executor to `new Promise`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43036229/1048572)!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From looks of it, the only change you need to do is replace following regular function:

```
return new Promise(async function(resolve, reject) {
```

with arrow function:

```
return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
```

**Reason is:**
arrow functions will properly bind with `this` (i.e. they will pass in `this`) of the context they were defined (*Disclaimer*: this is simplified explanation for now).

Comment: Thank you. I must admit I am poking around in the dark a bit, and happened upon the `async` after a huge amount of desperate experimenting till it worked because I need the functions to complete and return data when called, instead of the caller just jumping ahead without waiting. Is there any other potential side effect of the arrow function?

Comment: @TenG No in this context there is no side effect of arrow function that you should be concerned about. But as [Bergi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1048572/bergi) said in his comment to your original question, you passing `async' function to a `new Promise` is an `anti-pattern` (though it works, but u can miss on proper `error handling/rejection`). Read his linked question for details (not willing to take credit by putting his provided link here)!